# Unable to load class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver in apache-flume

Tags: oracle, apache, hibernate, flume

Im trying to make flume-ng-sql-source work with Apache Flume so I can stream Oracle DB to Kafka.

Find a basic tutorial here https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/11524.streaming-oracle-database-table-data-to-apache-kafka

Im using the following version 
Flume 1.8.0, flume-ng-sql-source 1.4.4 and ojdbc7.jar

Now when I try to lauch the agent I get the error
org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver]

Here is my flume.conf

```
agent.channels = ch1
agent.sinks = kafkaSink
agent.sources = sql-source

agent.channels.ch1.type = memory
agent.channels.ch1.capacity = 1000000
agent.sources.sql-source.channels = ch1

agent.sources.sql-source.type = org.keedio.flume.source.SQLSource

# URL to connect to database
agent.sources.sql-source.hibernate.connection.url =  jdbc:oracle:thin:@myoracleserver:1521:mydb

# Database connection properties
agent.sources.sql-source.hibernate.connection.user = user
agent.sources.sql-source.hibernate.connection.password = pass

agent.sources.sql-source.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
agent.sources.sql-source.hibernate.connection.driver_class = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver


agent.sources.sql-source.table = SCHEMA.TABLE


agent.sources.sql-source.columns.to.select = *

agent.sources.sql-source.status.file.name = sql-source.status

# Increment column properties
agent.sources.sql-source.incremental.column.name = id
# Increment value is from you want to start taking data from tables (0 will import entire table)
agent.sources.sql-source.incremental.value = 0

# Query delay, each configured milisecond the query will be sent
agent.sources.sql-source.run.query.delay=10000

# Status file is used to save last readed row
agent.sources.sql-source.status.file.path = /var/lib/flume
agent.sources.sql-source.status.file.name = sql-source.status


agent.sinks.kafkaSink.type=org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.brokerList=localhost:9092
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.topic=oradb
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.channel=ch1
agent.sinks.kafkaSink.batchSize=10
```

Here is my flume-env.sh

```
FLUME_CLASSPATH="/home/mache84/flume/apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/lib"
```

Here is the output when I launch flume

```
[mache84@localhost flume]$ apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/bin/flume-ng agent --conf /home/mache84/flume/apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/conf -f /home/mache84/flume/apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/conf/flume.conf -n agent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
Info: Sourcing environment configuration script /home/mache84/flume/apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/conf/flume-env.sh
Info: Including Hive libraries found via () for Hive access
+ exec /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/java -Xmx20m -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -cp '/home/mache84/flume/apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/conf:/home/mache84/flume/apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/lib/*:/home/mache84/flume/apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/lib:/home/mache84/flume/apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/plugins.d/sql-source/lib/*:/home/mache84/flume/apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/plugins.d/sql-source/libext/*:/lib/*' -Djava.library.path= org.apache.flume.node.Application -f /home/mache84/flume/apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/conf/flume.conf -n agent
2017-11-10 10:54:16,220 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.start(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:62)] Configuration provider starting
2017-11-10 10:54:16,223 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:134)] Reloading configuration file:/home/mache84/flume/apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/conf/flume.conf
2017-11-10 10:54:16,228 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:kafkaSink
2017-11-10 10:54:16,229 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:kafkaSink
2017-11-10 10:54:16,229 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:930)] Added sinks: kafkaSink Agent: agent
2017-11-10 10:54:16,229 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:kafkaSink
2017-11-10 10:54:16,229 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:kafkaSink
2017-11-10 10:54:16,229 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1016)] Processing:kafkaSink
2017-11-10 10:54:16,236 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration(FlumeConfiguration.java:140)] Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [agent]
2017-11-10 10:54:16,236 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadChannels(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:147)] Creating channels
2017-11-10 10:54:16,242 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.DefaultChannelFactory.create(DefaultChannelFactory.java:42)] Creating instance of channel ch1 type memory
2017-11-10 10:54:16,247 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadChannels(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:201)] Created channel ch1
2017-11-10 10:54:16,248 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.create(DefaultSourceFactory.java:41)] Creating instance of source sql-source, type org.keedio.flume.source.SQLSource
2017-11-10 10:54:16,250 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.keedio.flume.source.SQLSource.configure(SQLSource.java:63)] Reading and processing configuration values for source sql-source
2017-11-10 10:54:16,365 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit>(JavaReflectionManager.java:66)] HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2017-11-10 10:54:16,370 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.hibernate.Version.logVersion(Version.java:54)] HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
2017-11-10 10:54:16,372 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:239)] HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-11-10 10:54:16,373 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider(Environment.java:346)] HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-11-10 10:54:16,393 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.keedio.flume.source.HibernateHelper.establishSession(HibernateHelper.java:63)] Opening hibernate session
2017-11-10 10:54:16,472 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN - org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:93)] HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
2017-11-10 10:54:16,473 (conf-file-poller-0) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:361)] Source sql-source has been removed due to an error during configuration
org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:245)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:200)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:156)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:95)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
        at org.keedio.flume.source.HibernateHelper.establishSession(HibernateHelper.java:67)
        at org.keedio.flume.source.SQLSource.configure(SQLSource.java:73)
        at org.apache.flume.conf.Configurables.configure(Configurables.java:41)
        at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:326)
        at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:101)
        at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:141)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:230)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:242)
        ... 26 more
2017-11-10 10:54:16,475 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.create(DefaultSinkFactory.java:42)] Creating instance of sink: kafkaSink, type: org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
2017-11-10 10:54:16,479 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN - org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink.translateOldProps(KafkaSink.java:363)] topic is deprecated. Please use the parameter kafka.topic
2017-11-10 10:54:16,479 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN - org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink.translateOldProps(KafkaSink.java:374)] brokerList is deprecated. Please use the parameter kafka.bootstrap.servers
2017-11-10 10:54:16,479 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN - org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink.translateOldProps(KafkaSink.java:384)] batchSize is deprecated. Please use the parameter flumeBatchSize
2017-11-10 10:54:16,480 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink.configure(KafkaSink.java:314)] Using the static topic oradb. This may be overridden by event headers
2017-11-10 10:54:16,484 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:116)] Channel ch1 connected to [kafkaSink]
2017-11-10 10:54:16,488 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:137)] Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{kafkaSink=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@6542f090 counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{ch1=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: ch1}} }
2017-11-10 10:54:16,488 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:144)] Starting Channel ch1
2017-11-10 10:54:16,489 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:159)] Waiting for channel: ch1 to start. Sleeping for 500 ms
2017-11-10 10:54:16,524 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.register(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:119)] Monitored counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: ch1: Successfully registered new MBean.
2017-11-10 10:54:16,525 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:95)] Component type: CHANNEL, name: ch1 started
2017-11-10 10:54:16,990 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:171)] Starting Sink kafkaSink
2017-11-10 10:54:17,033 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.logAll(AbstractConfig.java:165)] ProducerConfig values:
        compression.type = none
        metric.reporters = []
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metadata.fetch.timeout.ms = 60000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        buffer.memory = 33554432
        timeout.ms = 30000
        key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        block.on.buffer.full = false
        ssl.key.password = null
        max.block.ms = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        client.id =
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        acks = 1
        batch.size = 16384
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        retries = 0
        max.request.size = 1048576
        value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        linger.ms = 0

2017-11-10 10:54:17,065 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser$AppInfo.<init>(AppInfoParser.java:82)] Kafka version : 0.9.0.1
2017-11-10 10:54:17,065 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser$AppInfo.<init>(AppInfoParser.java:83)] Kafka commitId : 23c69d62a0cabf06
2017-11-10 10:54:17,066 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.register(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:119)] Monitored counter group for type: SINK, name: kafkaSink: Successfully registered new MBean.
2017-11-10 10:54:17,066 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-1) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:95)] Component type: SINK, name: kafkaSink started
```

I have copied the lib ojdbc7.jar in

apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/lib and
apache-flume-1.8.0-bin/plugins.d/sql-source/libext/

This could be a very basic problem since I'm new to all this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was just that my ojdbc7.jar was a bad file.

I found a good one here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.3